# In Xcode's Allocations Instruments what does "count" mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

In the Call Tree's detail view I'm looking at Count

According to the Apple developer docs **Count** refers to *"The number of times the symbol was used"*

So what exactly does that mean? The number of times that method signature was invoked?
[image]
For this view controller which was initialized once in my profiling. What does this mean? viewDidLoad was invoked 3409 times?

How does the count 3409 relate to -viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What **count** means is the number of calls to allocate memory in this specific function and all of the functions it calls. So if it shows 5 then it has called 5 different functions.

Comment: Oh, so 3409 instances of *various* classes were made within this. That makes sense then.

Comment: Np glad to help @FangChen